# Custom PHPStan rul lto allow calling class method only from specific class

Tags: php, reflection, phpstan

I'm trying to write a custom phpstan rule to not allow other devs to call `Cart::save()` (`$cart->save()`) from everywhere in the codebase, but to call only from `CartRepository`, and if it's called outside of repository I want to see an error like `Calling Cart::save() method outside of CartRepository class is not allowed.`

I tried to do something like this

```
class CartSaveRule implements Rule
{
    public function getNodeType(): string
    {
        return MethodCall::class;
    }

    /**
     * @param MethodCall $node
     * @param Scope $scope
     * @return array
     */
    public function processNode(Node $node, Scope $scope): array
    {
        // Check if the method call is to the "save" method
        if ($node->name->toString() === 'save') {
            $className = $scope->getClassReflection()->getName();

            // Check if the method call is made from the Product class
            if ($className === 'Cart') {
                // Get the method call location
                $line = $node->getLine();
                $file = $scope->getFile();

                // Check if the method call is not made from inside the ProductRepository class
                if (!$this->isCalledFromProductRepository($scope)) {
                    return [
                        RuleErrorBuilder::message('Calling save() method of Cart class outside of CartRepository class is not allowed.')
                            ->line($line)
                            ->file($file)
                            ->build()
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return [];
    }


    private function isCalledFromRepository(Scope $scope): bool
    {
        // Check if the calling class is CartRepository or its subclass
        return  $scope->getClassReflection()->isSubclassOf('CartRepository');
    }
}
```

but it's not working as I expect, let's say in `Cart` I have a method :

```
    private function updateVariant()
    {
        $variant =  Variant::
            ->where('id', '=', $this->variantId)
            ->first();
        
        // logic to update variant        

        $variant->save();
    }
```

and my rule will scream on line `$variant->save();` because `save` is called by `Cart`, but it's not `Cart` related `save`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just override the `save()` method of the cart instead? Something like this:

```
<?php

class Cart
{
    public function save(object $repo = null)
    {
        if ($repo === null || !$repo instanceof CartRepository) {
            throw new Exception('Save the cart using the CartRepository' . "\n");
        }
        
        $repo->save($this);
    }
}

class CartRepository
{
    public function save(Cart $cart)
    {
        return 'saved!';
    }
}

$repo = new CartRepository();
$cart = new Cart();

try {
    $cart->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo $repo->save($cart);
```

This will output:

```
Save the cart using the CartRepository

saved!
```

You can try it here https://3v4l.org/uHW1e

Comment: the issue is that we are trying to move away from eloquent and replace all the saves and all other db query-related things in a single place. So having that in let's say DBRepo we can implement API repo and remove the model away at some point at ll. Overriding all such methods and injecting repo may work, but sounds also a bit weird not sure

Comment: also it'll be a infinity loop, because repo inside of it don't $cart->save()